# Compare how much items are equals in arrays using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, equals

what's up? I hope you going well.
So, my question is, I have a array with number that I have to compare with another arrays (like 1 to X), what is the best way to:

1º compare the arrays and retrieve the numbers that are equals.

2º the numbers of elements that are equal (without using .length on the array with numbers are equals).

Example:

```
Array 1 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16]

Array 2 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 12, 16, 17]
```

That way, the total numbers is `5`

And the numbers are: `[1, 3, 7, 9, 16]`

My method is using **forEach** and compare each item and using .length on the array with the numbers that are equals, there's another way or best way to do this?

Another example using more arrays:

```
Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15]

Arr2 = [

    [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],

    [2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],

    [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]

]

// Output

6, [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10]

5, [2, 5, 6, 7, 10]

7, [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15]
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: May you show us any code? The chance to get an answer will rise dramatically

Comment: Best way to do this would be to break everything into bits, then recursively recurse the set of bits into lookup tables for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `Set` for this purpose. You can create a `Set` from your first array and then any lookup in that Set (using `Set.has`) is O(1) efficiency.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 16];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 12, 16, 17];

const arr1Items = new Set(arr1);
const matched = arr2.filter(el => arr1Items.has(el));

console.log(matched.length, matched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arr2 is an array, not an object, your code would change accordingly

```
Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15]
Arr2 = [
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,],
    [2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15,]
]
```

Given that, the solution is a oneliner:

```
res = Arr2.map(a=>a.filter(x=>Arr1.indexOf(x)!=-1).length)
```

It should be straightforward but, just in case:

The `[].indexOf(el)` method give you the position of the parameter in the array, if that element is not present it will return `-1`. Therefore, the function

```
x => Arr1.indexOf(x)!=-1
```

returns `true` or `false` if x is present or not in the Arr1 array

The `[].filter(fn)` method use the `fn` function to evaluate every array element and give as result an array with the evaluated `true` elements.

```
a.filter(x => Arr1.indexOf(x)!=-1)
```

Means give me all the elements of array `a` presents in `Arr1`

Now we just have to count the lenght of that array

a.filter(x => Arr1.indexOf(x)!=-1).length

and pass this count to the `[].map(fn)` method to have the result we need.

Answer (score 0):

The function I wrote below will give the results you want, but remember the function returns an array of arrays, even if the second parameter had only one array or was an array of elements instead of array of arrays (Works for both).

```js
Arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15]

Arr2 = [
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],
    [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]
]

Arr3 = [1, 5, 6, 9, 12, 15, 17]


function check(base_array,search_values)
{
  if(base_array.length===0 || search_values.length===0)
  {
    return [];
  }
  else if(Array.isArray(search_values[0]))// Check if second parameter is an array of arrays.
  {
    var result=[];
    search_values.forEach(search=>{
      var result_sub=[];
      search.forEach(key=>{
        if(base_array.includes(key))
        {
          result_sub.push(key);
        }
      });
      result.push(result_sub);
    });
    return result;
  }
  else
  {
    var result=[];
    search_values.forEach(key=>{
        if(base_array.includes(key))
        {
          result.push(key);
        }
    });
    return [result];
  }
}

console.log("Array of Arrays");
console.log(check(Arr1,Arr2));

console.log("Array of Elements");
console.log(check(Arr1,Arr3));
```

From the returned result you can loop through the value to get the elements and the number of elements by checking length of array.

```
result.forEach(element=>{
    console.log(result.length, result);// number of elements doesn't have to be passed
});
```

What the Function does is it checks if any array is empty , then returns empty array `[]`, if the second array is an array of arrays it loops through each array and then to each element in the sub array and checks if it exists in the first array, else if the array was array of elements, then it just loops through the elements and checks if it exists in the first array. And returns the result stored